# Heckman IV with nonbinary dependent variable

Tags: r, regression, instrumental-variables, heckman

I have a model with a dependent variable $y$ as a percentage (budget residual) and independent variables $x$ as binary (policy dummy). 
I have an instrumental variable (IV) $z$ with a value between 0 and 1 for the policy dummy.

There is non-random selection into treatments as organizations can decide their own policy. 
I have data on $y$ for all observations.

My method is now IV regression, though I was wondering if a Heckman IV can also be performed. 
I tried to do it in R studio but I got confused as my dependent variable is not binary.

Hope someone can explain whether Heckman IV might be the right method here or not.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "Heckman IV"?  I don't know any implementation of Heckman selection models that have dependent variable limited to [0,1] but depeding on how your data actually looks like you may get away with ordinary Heckman model (with unlimited dependent variable).  (`sampleSelection` package does that).

Comment: Yes I meant Sample selection or the heckit command in r studio. I thought I read in an ecnoometrics book that the dependent variable should be binary.

Comment: In this case it should not be binary, but limited to $[0,1]$.  I don't know any implementations, but why don't you start with ordinary (unlimited) dependent variable and see how far can you get with this?